# Can I create a histogram/bar graph from a list in python? typeError: expected str, found List

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, beautifulsoup, gensim

I am using matplotlib, pandas and gensim. I am trying to create a histogram based on frequent words by extracting text directly from a website. I am receiving a typeError in this instance:

```
text = ','.join(map(str, description_list))
word_frequency = Counter(" ".join(description_list[0]).split()).most_common(10)
```

from this part of my code:

```
#start of problems
data = {
    "description": [text_corpus]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
description_list = df['description'].values.tolist()

text = ','.join(map(str, description_list))
word_frequency = Counter(" ".join(description_list[0]).split()).most_common(10)

# `most_common` returns a list of (word, count) tuples
words = [word for word, _ in word_frequency]
counts = [counts for _, counts in word_frequency]

plt.bar(words, counts)
plt.title("10 most frequent tokens in description")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.xlabel("Words")
plt.show()

print(text)
```

Here is the initial part of my code, which works in extracting textual data from a website:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint
from re import X
import string
from tokenize import Token
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-61294585"
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()   

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

document = text 

text_corpus = [text]

# Create a set of frequent words
stoplist = set('for a of the and to in'.split(' '))
# Lowercase each document, split it by white space and filter out stopwords
texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split() if word not in stoplist]
         for document in text_corpus]

# Count word frequencies
from collections import defaultdict
frequency = defaultdict(int)
for text in texts:
    for token in text:
        frequency[token] += 1

# Only keep words that appear more than once
text_corpus = [[token for token in text if frequency[token] > 1] for text in texts]
pprint.pprint(text_corpus)
```

I am new to Python so please any advice will help. Please let me know If I have something fundamentally wrong with my code, and If i have to restart.

Or if not, if i could be pointed in the right direction in creating graphs from frequent words would be much appreciated or how to convert this particular list into a string.

Additional question:
Would it be better to search for specific words from a website instead of extracting all text?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should include inside your question the entire, multiline error you're receiving – including any 'traceback' info showing involved lines-of-code & files – to make it easier for answerers to know what exactly is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you've got `text_corpus` you may proceed as follows:

```
#url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72091588/can-i-create-a-histogram-bar-graph-from-a-list-in-python-typeerror-expected-st"

counter = Counter(text_corpus[0]).most_common(10)
words, counts = list(zip(*counter))
plt.bar(words, counts)
```

[image]

Comment: I think your code may be reduced even further, but my point here: you do not need passing your data through pandas at all.

Comment: @StockPrice If that solved your problem you may kindly think about accepting/upvoting

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `[0]`, it should be:

```
word_frequency = Counter(" ".join(description_list[0][0]).split()).most_common(10)
```

Output:

[image]